# What is this plant and how to take care of it?

Tags: identification, plant-health, growth

I live in Bangalore, India and was gifted a plant 4 weeks back. It's a small one, has small thick leaves.

[image: Plant image]

It was fine for couple of weeks. After which the leaves turned a little yellow, 6 to 7 leaves became soft and withered off. Even the plant itself has started to droop and become very floppy.

I have kept the plant indoors, out of sunlight, watering it every alternate day. The soil is moist to the touch.

Please help me identify the plant and provide tips on getting it healthy.

--- UPDATE (30 Jan 2020) ---

It's been a day since I kept the plant outside so that the sun shines for an hour or so only in the morning.

:'(  the plant is completely limp now.

Only one stem looks a little stiff but overall it looks like it's in a bad state.
Can I do anything, to help the plant heal?

[image: Plant going limp - top view.]

[image: Plant going limp - different angle.]

Comment: Thick leaves indicate that it's probably a semi-succulent. Don't water it until the soil is dry to the touch. You can probably get by with water only every two weeks in the winter. Also, the pot MUST have a drainage hole. After you water it, discard any water remaining in the saucer after half a hour.

Comment: I also needs some sunlight.  Morning sun will be good enough.  Or bright indirect light.   Your plant is too wet and not getting enough sunlight.   I think is a Peperomia. Jurp is right they are semi-succulents.   Water it when the soil is almost completely dry, but not all the way.

Comment: @Jurp, thanks for the tips. The pot has a drain hole. I have stopped watering for now.

Comment: @Aloe, I've kept the plant outside so that it gets a little bit of direct sunlight every day.

But as you can see in the update made to the question, the condition of the plant has gone down. Will the plant heal? Will it get better if I leave it outside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the perfect opportunity to take a cutting of the plant to root.    You might be able to get a new plant started even if the older plant dies.  The roots on the old plant might be too compromised at this point.  Take a cutting that is atleast 10 cm (4") long if possible.  Remove two to four of the lower leaves.  You can take the cutting and put it in water to get new roots or you can plant it in dry soil.  Wait about a week to water for the first time.  When you water use a spray bottle to water just where there might be new roots instead of the entire pot.  As the roots fill the pot you will increase the amount of water you give the plant.

Once your plant is fully rooted, use a bamboo chopstick (unpolished or any sealant applied) to determine in the future if you plant needs more water.   Insert the stick in the soil and check to see if it is wet in about 10 mins.

Based on your new pictures I would say with confidence it is a Peperomia.  This type of Perperomia wants less water than the tropical rain-forest type.  This types I believe grows on rock ledges.  Water it constantly touching the roots, but the roots are also dry, because the water does not stay put.  In a pot, you are going to soak it.  Then let it dry out before you water it again.

Your soil did not look like it has much for drainage material like perlite or just small gravel.  This is help provide air pockets in the soil, so your plant does not suffocate in water.

Comment: Thanks Aloe, will do it today and update the progress in few days. Fingers crossed I can heal it back to life or at least get a cutting done successfully.